# VBA code only deleting part of what it whould be

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below code. I want this to delete every item in Column z that is NA... it is only deleting the first section of NA and not deleting the others. Is there something I need to add to this to get it to delete all NA's

```
Sub Delete_NA()

Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim StartRow, StopRow As Integer

For x = 0 To LastRow
    If (Range("Y2").Offset(x, 0) = "NA") Then
    Range("Y2").Offset(x, 0).EntireRow.Delete
    x = x - 1

End If
Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: loop from the bottom up (LastRow to 1 step -1) and get rid of the x = x -1 part.  You'll get much more consistent results.

Comment: I removed the X=X-1, but I am not sure how to change the code to show it looping from the bottom up... Any suggestions?

Comment: for x = LastRow to 1 Step -1

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code

```
Sub Delete_NA()
    Dim LastRow, x As Long
    LastRow = Range("Y" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For x = LastRow To 1 Step -1
        If Range("Y" & x).Value = "NA" Then
            Range("Y" & x).EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlUp
        End If
    Next x
End Sub
```